# how to add my custom js to footer vai reference

Tags: module

i want to add custom js to footer:

i am using below code in admin > category > custom design

```
<reference name="footer">
<action method="addJs"><script>design/fabric_with_gestures.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

addJs function is not working because of it only call  at head and `addJs()` function class is `Mage_Page_Html_Head`.

You need **call a phtml file from footer reference and on this phtml file you need call the file using $this->getSkinUrl();**

Comment: ok thanks what it i want to add in last of all js